# How access the html element of a Popup?

Tags: leaflet

How retrieve the html element of a **Popup** that has been bonded to a marker ?

```py
#this is not JS but Python (for frontend)

#function that need access to the html element.
def aFunction(ev):
    ev.target #return the leaflet obj -> ~ <javascript object [object Object]>
    ev.originalEvent.target #return the <img> of the marker, not the Popup


#binding
window.L.marker([2,3]).bindPopup('inside the popup').once('click', aFunction)
```